# Storing image resource id in Sqlite database and retrieving it in int array

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing an online shopping app, where I am storing all the product details in Sqlite database, along with resource ids of product images. I am retrieving those ids(eg: R.drawable.image1), in order to display the images,  stored in drawable folder.

The ids are retrieved precisely, but an exception occurs, as "InvalidNumberFormatException: R.drawable.image1". I have stored all the ids, as VARCHAR, in sqlite. How can I store these ids in an int array, after they are retrieved as string values ?

I am displaying these images and other product details using recyclerview. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do this.  There's a major problem with storing image ids in the database-  the numbers aren't stable.  Each time you recompile the app, the values can change.  If you add or remove any resource, the entire mapping can change.  It isn't a stable method of storing that data.  Using the drawable's name and converting to id would be more stable.

Comment: @GabeSechan : Can you please suggest me how to do what you suggested? I am a newbie to Android development. Also. If you have any other way to use the images in drawable folder, please suggest. My main aim is to use the precise image for the particular product, from drawable folder using recycler view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just store name of image in database and use below code to get its id

```
private void loadImage(String mImageName, ImageView mImageIcon){
int resID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(mImageName , "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
            if(resID!=0) {//The associated resource identifier. Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)
                mImageIcon.setImageResource(resID);
            }
}
```